# Printing one sheet with duplex enabled fails HP psc 2510

Tags: printing, hp

Rather old issue I have with Ubuntu 14.10 (currently 15.04 beta) and the HP psc 2510. Issue started at I believe 13.04 (perhaps 12.10), but would be great if someone has a solution.

Situations:

- When I print an even amount of sides and select duplex, all goes fine;
- When I print a single sided page, without selecting duplex, all goes fine;
- When I print an uneven amount of sides, the last side will be printed, but the paper won't come out of the printer.

The paper is nicely pulled into the duplex unit, turned and aligned to start printing a new side. But none is available, so the sheet should be ejected. I need to pull the power and connect it again to get the paper out.

- This happens all the time;
- This happens on two different Ubuntu machines (one still available);

I don't think the printer is broken as:

- This doesn't happen from a Windows PC to the same printer;
- This doesn't happen from a Mac to the same printer.

Driver, according to CUPS: HP PSC 2500 Series, hpcups 3.15.2 (color, 2-sided printing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my printer recently 'died' answering this question won't be needed anymore for me.